# web designers icon avatars?

Tags: graphics

Anybody know how these are made. I see them a lot, mostly web designers have them. Are they hand made in psd or illustrator or is there a web service that converts real photos?

[image]

Comment: I think it's safe to say those were drawn by a human. They have enough commonalities that a Mr. Potato Head-style app could be at play, but I'd assume they're just from the same artist.

Comment: Has your questioned been answered or do you need more information on this topic?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://www.photoshopsupport.com/tutorials/jennifer/favicon.html

Summary:

Photoshop + Photoshop Plugin + Save As... Favicon.ico + File Type 'Windows Icon' = your icon works.

Put in the same directory as your main page and put the following HTML inside the head:

OR

Skip all of that and use a .gif or .png (Won't work in IE), and put the following HTML inside of the head:

or

Comment: your answer is 80% off but..thanks for your effort. edit your answer a little bit more.